# Pass ImageView to next activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, bitmap, imageview

I've been searching and searching and searching for days but I can't seem to find what I'm doing wrong, so you are my last hope!

I have my first activity with multiple images. When I press one I want the second activity to open showing only the clicked image. I'm trying to convert the clicked image to bitmap and then sending it with the intent so that my second activity can retreive it.

This the code for my first Activity (the bitmap....'drawable' is underlined in red, and so is intent.....'this, SubActivity.class'). What am I doing wrong?

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final ImageView imgview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
        imgview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Haal de drawable op uit de imageview
                Drawable drawable = imgview.getDrawable();

                // Zet de drawable om naar een ByteArray zodat we deze kunnen versturen met een intent
                // want we kunnen niet zomaar een drawable in een intent gooien
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(drawable);
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
                byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();

                // Maak de intent aan en stuur de ByteArray mee waar de drawable in zit
                Intent intent;
                intent = new Intent(this,SubActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("witte_tulp_small", b);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And this is the code in my second Activity:

```
public class SubActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sub);

        // Intent uitlezen
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        byte[] b = extras.getByteArray("witte_tulp_small");

        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(b, 0, b.length);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

        image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    }

}
```

Comment: send image data or unqiue identifier related to image using bundle while starting second activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both Activities are in the same app, you can just pass the drawable id:

In `MainActivity`

```
intent.putExtra("witte_tulp_small", R.id.image);
```

In `SubActivity`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sub);

    // Intent uitlezen
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    int resId = extras.getInt("witte_tulp_small");
    ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
    image.setImageResource(resId);
}
```

Comment: What should I write instead of the "//..." ?

Comment: Sorry, that's just the same `findViewById()` you have in your own code, I've pasted it into my answer. No need for bitmap stuff with this solution. But it's limited to where both activities are in the same app.

Comment: Ok, I've done this and I'm almost there! Only the "extras" in int resId = extras.getInt("witte_tulp_small"); is red. The error says : cannot resolve symbol 'extras'. Any idea why?

Comment: Again, it wasn't the complete code, just the bits you needed to change. I've updated my answer to show the full code for `onCreate()` now.

Answer (score 2):

Bitmap are `Parcelable`. You can put parcelable objects in bundle or intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SubActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("bitmap", bitmap);
```

and read back on the other end

```
Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) getIntent().getParcelableExtra("bitmap");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should only send the *source* of the image to the other activity, which will re-create the imageview